# SignalR, ASP.NET 5 and CORS

Tags: signalr, cors, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use SignalR with my MVC6 application, but I encounter problem with CORS.

First : If I host my index.html file on http://localhost:1234/index.html (same as my web app) it's working.
But when I host it elsewhere (for example in file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/index.html), I have this error :

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Of course, I try to enable CORS, this is my startup file :

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSignalR();

        services.AddCors();
        var policy = new Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.Core.CorsPolicy();
        policy.Origins.Add("*");
        policy.Headers.Add("*");
        policy.Methods.Add("*");
        services.ConfigureCors(x => x.AddPolicy("allowall", policy));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors("allowall");
        app.UseSignalR();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

But now, I have another error :

> A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'null' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

Then I try with :

```
policy.SupportsCredentials = false;
```

but still getting same error.

What should I do ?

Comment: Downvoted. The title of this issue is kind of misleading. It should made more clear, that is concerns about file serving instead of http serving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen with SignalR team, this is working on http://localhost:port but not on file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/index.html and this is normal.